# Is it possible to push a zip file to app center through azure pipeline?

Tags: azure-pipelines, visual-studio-app-center

I tried following

```yaml
- task: AppCenterDistribute@3
  inputs:
    serverEndpoint: 'AppCenter-Connection'
    appSlug: 'Organisation/TestHarness'
    appFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildNumber).zip'
    releaseNotesOption: 'input'
    releaseNotesInput: 'Build $(Build.BuildNumber)'
    destinationType: 'groups'
```

But I get the error

`##[error]"{\"error\":\"Error: Missing required params from body: build_version, Service id: f734ab18-06ca-4882-a3fb-14cc2a7897897\"}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's able to push a zip file.  If you using platform which is WPF or WinForms. Please add build Version explicitly:

> *buildVersion*
>
> (Optional) The build version of the uploading binary which needs to be
>   specified for .zip and .msi. This value will be ignored unless the
>   platform is WPF or WinForms.

Otherwise, take a look at this similar issue here: [Missing required params from body](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/7699). Seems the issue is related to signing.

Kindly check if the solution in above link such as fix code signing/create a plist file  also work for you.